# WT save file dialog window?

Tags: c++, api, file, openfiledialog, wt

Hello fellow WT users. I have a problem with enabling the user the ability to choose a save location for some data in my application. I have noticed that WT has an absence of an easy to use save/open file dialog boxes or widgets for the purposes of browsing the hard drive of a machine for a save location or a file to load. I would imagine both of such widgets return the path of said location or file to load, but alas I have not found any. I have also looked at [Wt::WFileUpload Class](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/reference/html/classWt_1_1WFileUpload.html) but had a hard time understanding how exactly to use it, and after googling around some examples determined it is probably not what I am looking for.

Why not use windows OpenFileDialog? Well, in this project I have WT overlayed over a full screen application as a UI, if any other windows open the application would minimize(which is bad). Which is why I'm looking to browse the hard drive in just WT.

After thinking about this for a while, I figured why not just write my own file browser? So after a bit of digging I came across the [MVC Tree Views](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/widgets/trees-tables/mvc-tree-views). Those look pretty close to [Windows Open File Dialog](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+open+file+dialog&espv=210&es_sm=122&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=MmiWUuX4BpWosQSfy4CgCQ&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAQ&biw=1137&bih=622#es_sm=122&espv=210&q=windows+7+save+file+dialog&spell=1&tbm=isch&imgdii=_), except that I would need to write my own code for building and displaying the trees, browsing the hard drive with boost, then handling all the saving and loading myself.

Which I am not apposed to, it just seemed reasonable to check with the community before I jump the gun and write a lot of code that I potentially might not need to. It seems odd that WT does not have anything to support hard drive browsing, which brings me here.

Does anyone know anything about a Widget, or a clever combination of Widgets, or another WT method to enable the user to browse the hard drive of the machine in just WT?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I would check out [this thread](http://redmine.webtoolkit.eu/boards/2/topics/8074?r=8081#message-8081) on the official Wt redmine and either link back to this question on SO or ask the same one there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filetreetable example does more or less what you ask.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up using the TreeTable to display the hard-drive and boost to traverse it. Too bad WT does not have its own Save/Load window dialogs.